# remove object from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How can I remove an object from a reversed `NSArray`.

Currently I have a `NSMutableArray`, then I reverse it with

```
NSArray* reversedCalEvents = [[calEvents reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

now I need to remove at item from `reversedCalEvents` or `calEvents` and automatically refresh the table the array is displayed in based on conditions.
i.e.

```
if(someInt == someOtherInt){
    remove object at index 0
}
```

How can I do this? I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a more functional approach using *Key-Value Coding*:

```
@implementation NSArray (Additions)

- (instancetype)arrayByRemovingObject:(id)object {
    return [self filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != %@", object]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 12):

You will need a mutable array in order to remove an object. Try creating `reversedCalEvents` with `mutableCopy`.

```
NSMutableArray *reversedCalEvents = [[calEvents reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];

if (someInt == someOtherInt)
{
    [reversedCalEvents removeObject:object];
}
```

Comment: NSArray by definition is non-mutable which means once created you cannot change the contents of the allocated array

Comment: Yes. That's why I used NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2):

NSArray is not editable, so that you cannot modify it.

You can copy that array to NSMutableArray and remove objects from it. And finally reassign the values of the NSMutableArray to your NSArray.

From here you will get a better idea...
[NSArray + remove item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728475/nsarray-remove-item-from-array/1728505#1728505)

Answer (score 0):

First you should read up on the [`NSMutableArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class itself to familiarize yourself with it.

Second, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111866/868193) should show you an easy way to remove the objects from your NSMutableArray instance.

Third, you can cause the UITableView to refresh by sending it the `reloadData` message.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:-

```
NSMutableArray* reversedCalEvents = [[[calEvents reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] mutableCopy];
            [reversedCalEvents removeLastObject];
```