# Removing object from array doesnt remove anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have:

```
self.path = [self pathByCopyingFile:@"Notes List.plist"];
self.data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.path];
self.notes = [self.data objectForKey:@"Notes"];
```

Then in a button (Button method definitely gets called):

```
NSString *title = self.navigationItem.title;
         //Filter notes array by title
         NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title =[cd] %@", title];
         NSArray * titleArray = [self.notes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

         //delete all the notes with the old title name
         [self.notes removeObject:titleArray];
         NSLog(@"%@", self.notes);
```

At this point, self.notes still contains the items and i dont know why they arnt being removed

Comment: Because NSArray is not mutable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426570/remove-object-from-nsarray

Comment: my "self.notes" is mutable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to remove an array from the array. That's not what you want. I believe your goal is to remove all of the objects in the `titleArray` from your `notes` array.

And this doesn't even consider that `self.notes` is probably an `NSArray` and not an `NSMutableArray`.

If `self.notes` is mutable you can use the `removeObjectsInArray:`.

```
[self.notes removeObjectsInArray:titleArray];
```