# how to delete several elements in an NSarray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an array with number of elements. I want to delete several elements in one step at different index (i.e I want to delete elements from index zero to index seven, at the same time I also want to delete elements from index 15 to index 21. Is this possible?

Comment: Not in one step. But if you iterate through the array backwards you can delete them all in one "pass".  Or do the straight-forward forward loop and copy to a new array, omitting what you don't want.

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: @HotLicks...thanks for the suggestion can you post some code regarding this how to solve this problem.

Comment: objective c....xcode(iphone)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an NSMutableIndexSet to contain the array indexes you want to remove.

Example:

Create an `NSMutableIndexSet:`

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
```

Add the array indexes that you want to delete to it:

```
[indexes addIndex:3];
[indexes addIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(5, 3)];
```

That will provide array indexes 3, 5, 6, 7

Remove the indexed item from the mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
[mutableArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

If needed:
    array = [mutableArray copy];

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
[array removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 10)];
```

or

```
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]];
```

Find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectsInRange:) and [here](http://ios.eezytutorials.com/nsmutablearray-by-example.php#.VMZ1jy6UeQw).

Comment: @shudima....can i add multiple ranges in this syntax using comma like             [array removeObjectsInRange:<#(0-7),(15-21)#>]

Comment: Not using these methods. I'm afraid you have to write something for yourself for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(void)removeObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes` of `NSMutableArray`

> NSArray is not mutable, that is, you cannot modify it. You should take
>   a look at NSMutableArray. Check out the "Removing Objects" section,
>   you'll find there many functions that allow you to remove items:

Citated from: [NSArray + remove item from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728475/nsarray-remove-item-from-array)

Also see [Removes the objects at the specified indexes from the array](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectsAtIndexes:)

Comment: `[anArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:` is handy, several methods return an `NSIndexSet`.

Comment: @Zaph..can i remove multiple elements using commas here like [anArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:0,1,2,3,5,10,17].. like this

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `removeObjectsInRange:`? Of course you'd have to call it however many times to delete multiple ranges in sequence but you could easily write a category function that can take care of it.

```
- (void)removeObjectsAtRanges:(NSMutableArray *)ranges {
    for range in ranges {
        [self removeObjectsInRange:range];
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this in xcode but you get the general idea.

Edit: As was pointed out, once you delete a range, you'd have to dynamically shift all the other ranges so you don't go out of bounds.

Comment: You could iterate `ranges` in reverse. Much easier.